# Rails file_field for upload not appearing on edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, filefield

I've added the ability to upload files to my model named `requests`.  I have a secondary model named `request_files` that houses a carrierwave uploader named `file`.

When I create a new request, the upload button appears and I can upload files.  If I upload files, they appear in my show and edit views, and I can add more files in the edit form.  If I do not upload files when I initially create a new `request`, the upload button does not appear in my edit form.  ***I would like the upload button to appear in the form for both `new` and `edit`.***

**Here is the part of the form with the fields for request_files:**

```
<div class="clear">
  <b>Upload Files:</b>
  <%= f.fields_for :request_files do |p| %>
     <div class="field">
       <%= p.file_field :file, :multiple => true, name: "request_files[file][]" %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>

   <% if params[:controller] == "requests" && params[:action] == "edit" %> 
     <b>Uploaded Files:</b>
        <table class="table">
        <% @request.request_files.each do |p| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= p.file_url.split("/").last %></td>
            <td><%= button_to "Download File", {action: "download", controller: "requests", :file => p.file}  %></td>
            <!--<td><%= link_to "Delete File", p, method: :delete %></td>-->
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
   <% end %>
```

**This is the entire controller file:**

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  handles_sortable_columns
  before_filter :sales_check, only: [:create, :new]
  before_filter :admin_check, only: [:destroy]
  # GET /requests
  # GET /requests.json
  def index
    order = sortable_column_order, "request_number desc"
   if params[:requests].nil?
       @requests = Request.paginate page: params[:page], order: order, per_page: 100
    else
      @requests = Request\
      .by_request_number(params[:requests][:request_number])\
      .by_keyword(params[:requests][:description])\
      .by_regional_sales_mgr(params[:requests][:regional_sales_mgr])\
      .by_product_line(params[:requests][:product_line])\
      .by_quote_number(params[:requests][:quote_number])\
      .by_customer(params[:requests][:customer])\
      .by_created_before(params[:requests]['created_before(1i)'], params[:requests]['created_before(2i)'], params[:requests]['created_before(3i)'])\
      .by_created_after(params[:requests]['created_after(1i)'], params[:requests]['created_after(2i)'], params[:requests]['created_after(3i)'])\
      .paginate page: params[:page], order: order, per_page: 100

    end


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @requests }
    end
  end

  def index_open
    order = sortable_column_order, "request_number desc"
    @requests = Request.by_open_requests.by_non_released_requests.paginate page: params[:page], order: order, per_page: 100

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :template => "requests/index" }
      format.json { render json: @requests }
    end
  end

  # GET /requests/1
  # GET /requests/1.json
  def show
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @request_files = @request.request_files.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @request }
    end
  end

  # GET /requests/new
  # GET /requests/new.json
  def new
    @request = Request.new
    @request = @request.incrament(@request)
    @request_file = @request.request_files.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @request }
    end
  end

  # GET /requests/1/edit
  def edit
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @request_files = @request.request_files.all
    if @request_files.nil?
      @request_file = @request.request_files.build
    else

    end
  end

  # POST /requests
  # POST /requests.json
  def create
    @request = Request.new(params[:request])
    @request = @request.created_status(@request)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        params[:request_files]['file'].each do |a|
          @request_file = @request.request_files.create!(:file => a, :request_id => @request.id)
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @request, status: :created, location: @request }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /requests/1
  # PUT /requests/1.json
  def update
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.update_attributes(params[:request])
        params[:request_files]['file'].each do |a|
          @request_file = @request.request_files.create!(:file => a, :request_id => @request.id)
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /requests/1
  # DELETE /requests/1.json
  def destroy
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @request.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to requests_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def submit_eng

    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = @email[:message]
    @request = @request.eng_status(@request)
    @subject = @email[:subject]
    @additional_emails = @email[:recipient]

    respond_to do |format|
      RequestMailer.submit_additional(@request, @message, @additional_emails, @subject).deliver if @additional_emails != ""
      RequestMailer.notify_a9(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "A9"
      RequestMailer.notify_a7(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "A7"
      RequestMailer.notify_ag(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "AG"
      RequestMailer.notify_af(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "AF"
      RequestMailer.notify_S3(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "S3"
      RequestMailer.notify_legacy(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "Legacy"
      RequestMailer.notify_kkpro(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "K/Kpro"
      RequestMailer.notify_emw(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "EMW"
      RequestMailer.notify_hd(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "HD"
      RequestMailer.notify_nm(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "Non-Metallic"

      @request.update_attributes(params[:request])
      format.html { redirect_to home_url, alert: "SIR has been submitted to engineering.  Please push up the revision level and resubmit if you make any changes." }
      format.json { render json: @requests }
    end
  end

  def submit_mfg

    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = @email[:message]
    @request = @request.mfg_status(@request)
    @subject = @email[:subject]
    @additional_emails = @email[:recipient]

    respond_to do |format|
      RequestMailer.submit_additional(@request, @message, @additional_emails, @subject).deliver if @additional_emails != ""
      RequestMailer.notify_mfg(@request, @message, @subject).deliver 

      @request.update_attributes(params[:request])
      format.html { redirect_to home_url, alert: "SIR has been submitted to manufacturing.  Please resubmit if you make any changes." }
      format.json { render json: @requests }
    end
  end

  def reject

    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = @email[:message]
    @request = @request.reject_status(@request)
    @subject = @email[:subject]
    @additional_emails = @email[:recipient]

    respond_to do |format|
      RequestMailer.reject_additional(@request, @message, @additional_emails, @subject).deliver if @additional_emails != ""
      RequestMailer.reject(@request, @message, @subject).deliver 

      @request.update_attributes(params[:request])
      format.html { redirect_to home_url, alert: "SIR has been returned to sales marked as incomplete." }
      format.json { render json: @requests }
    end
  end

  def submit_acct

    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = @email[:message]
    @request = @request.acct_status(@request)
    @subject = @email[:subject]
    @additional_emails = @email[:recipient]

    respond_to do |format|
      RequestMailer.submit_additional(@request, @message, @additional_emails, @subject).deliver if @additional_emails != ""
      RequestMailer.notify_acct(@request, @message, @subject).deliver 

      @request.update_attributes(params[:request])
      format.html { redirect_to home_url, alert: "SIR has been submitted to accounting.  Please resubmit if you make any changes." }
      format.json { render json: @requests }
    end
  end

  def submit_sales

    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = @email[:message]
    @request = @request.complete_status(@request)
    @subject = @email[:subject]
    @additional_emails = @email[:recipient]

    respond_to do |format|
      RequestMailer.submit_additional(@request, @message, @additional_emails, @subject).deliver if @additional_emails != ""
      RequestMailer.notify_sales(@request, @message, @subject).deliver 

      @request.update_attributes(params[:request])
      format.html { redirect_to home_url, alert: "SIR has been submitted to Sales.  Please resubmit if you make any changes." }
      format.json { render json: @requests }
    end
  end

  def submit_sor
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = @email[:message]
    @request = @request.sor_status(@request)
    @subject = @email[:subject]
    @additional_emails = @email[:recipient]

    respond_to do |format|
      RequestMailer.submit_additional(@request, @message, @additional_emails, @subject).deliver if @additional_emails != ""
      RequestMailer.notify_a9(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "A9"
      RequestMailer.notify_a7(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "A7"
      RequestMailer.notify_ag(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "AG"
      RequestMailer.notify_af(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "AF"
      RequestMailer.notify_S3(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "S3"
      RequestMailer.notify_legacy(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "Legacy"
      RequestMailer.notify_kkpro(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "K/Kpro"
      RequestMailer.notify_emw(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "EMW"
      RequestMailer.notify_hd(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "HD"
      RequestMailer.notify_nm(@request, @message, @subject).deliver if @request.product_line == "Non-Metallic"
      RequestMailer.notify_mfg(@request, @message, @subject).deliver 

      @request.update_attributes(params[:request])
      format.html { redirect_to home_url, alert: "SOR has been created.  An email has been sent to the appropriate personnel." }
      format.json { render json: @requests }
    end
  end

  def close_sir
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @request = @request.complete_status(@request)

    respond_to do |format|
      @request.update_attributes(params[:request])
      format.html { redirect_to home_url, alert: "SIR has been marked as complete." }
      format.json { render json: @requests }
    end
  end

  def download
    @request_file = RequestFile.where('id LIKE ?', params[:id])
    @path = @request_file.each do |p|
      return p.file_url
    end
    @name = params[:file]
    # for windows testing
    @file = "c://users/sabrams/engdb/public#{@name}"
    # for linux live system
    #@file = "/srv/engdb/public#{@name}"
    send_file( @file,
    :disposition => 'inline',
    :x_sendfile => true )

  #rescue TypeError
  #    redirect_to @request, :flash => { :alert => "File not found.  Please try again or contact support." }
  end 

  private
   def request_params
      params.require(:request).permit(:request_number, request_files_attributes: [:id, :request_id, :file])
   end

end
```

Comment: please paste your `form_for` call

Comment: `<%= form_for(@request) do |f| %>`

Comment: Can you try `<%= f.fields_for :request_files, @request.request_files do |p| %>`

Comment: also, the name of the file filed is strange, you could let Rails calculate it for you. But you might need to change something else, for it to work calculated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. On your controller `#new` method you have have `.build`, but you do not have in the `#edit` method, only inside of that condition. My guess is that's why it doesn't appear.